# Animate background not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-position

I have done this sort of thing before, but it's not working for me now...

I have a container div, and a div inside with partly transparent image. When the user hovers over the container div I would like the background on that div to move 0px -56px. I have tried this using animate like I usually do, its not working. Initially my old script would not work in 1.6 so Im back on 1.4.2, its making no difference, so maybe my code is just rubbish...

```
$('.trans_bg').css({"background-position":"0 0"});
$('.trans_bg').hover(
function() {
    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "(0px -56px)"},{duration:300}); 
},
function(){
    $(this).animate({backgroundPosition: "(0px 0px)"},{duration:300});
})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, just remove parentheses when setting the new position:

```
$('.trans_bg').css({ backgroundPosition: "0 0" });
$('.trans_bg').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundPosition: "0px -56px"}, 300);
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundPosition: "0px 0px"}, 300);
});
```

But unfortunatelly, jQuery can't animate backgroundPosition natively.

But there is a great plugin to do it: [Background-Position Animation Plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/).

Grab it to your project so the typed code just starts working!

Comment: Hi, I took out the () and the background moves, but it moves instantly like standard CSS, not a smooth animation. I will try that plugin you linked. Strange thing is I have done this before - http://tinyurl.com/6gk9bgc

Comment: Looks like the plugin is working really well. Thanks for the link. Still confuses me why I need it this time, but as long as it works! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I really can't answer why you don't needed it before. But of course, you can do it without the plugin if you animate each axis separetly. See [here](http://jsbin.com/uqeto4/edit).

Comment: Fantastic! That's EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you :D

Comment: Just a quick update, although backgroundPositionX and backgroundPositionY worked in some browsers, I didn't want to work in firefox (on mac at least, not sure about windows yet)...so I ended up using the plugin code after all. Its looking good though.

Comment: Thanks about pointing it to us. I never tested it on Mac Firefox. Here on Windows 7 with Firefox 4 is working well.

Comment: No Problem. Sometimes I think having one browser would really save time. One browser to rule them all :D

Comment: Hi again! I have been having real issues with a slider on my site. I was using 1.4.2. I changed to 1.6.1 and the slider started working fine. However, the animation on the backgrounds has broken again. I can get it to work in IE, Opera, Safari and all IE's - even IE6! But, both FF on mac and windows 7 are broken for me. I just installed the latest FF on windows and it doesn't work. Any ideas? That fiddle doesn't work in FF for me....